# Strange behaviour in FF32 using CSS rotateY transformation with small values (JSfiddle)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, transform

I am planning to achieve a 3D-transformation of an HTML element (rotateY, to be exact) that is controlled by mouse movement using javascript. This results in tiny values that can be handled well by all major browsers with the exception of **Firefox 32** (**it worked with version 19**, which I updated from).

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1m9q730s/6/) for a demo.

Here's what happens:

As long as the *rotateY* value is within a certain margin ( -0.08 < *value* > 0.08 ), Firefox assumes a *transformation-origin* that equals x=0, even if set otherwise. It is hard to see in the demo, as the values are so low, but the effect is noticeable. As soon as the value exceeds said margin (upwards or downwards), the transformation seems to be cleared and *transformation-origin* to be set to *50%*.
Applied to an animation or mouse-controlled movement, it leads to a very annoying judder towards the center of the transformation.

I would appreciate any kind of hint or workaround for this.

Cheers!

**HTML**

```
<div id="base">
    <span id="status"></span>
</div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="smaller" value="-0.1">-0.1</button>
    <button id="muchSmaller" value="-0.01">-0.01</button>
    <button id="bigger" value="+0.1">+0.1</button>
    <button id="muchBigger" value="+0.01">+0.01</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#base, #top{
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-size:cover;
}
#base{
    height:200px;
    background:url(http://s28.postimg.org/mh21gch0d/base.png) transparent no-repeat 0 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:#555;
    padding-top:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#top{
    height:300px;
    background:url(http://s28.postimg.org/tyb8vk6jh/top.png) transparent no-repeat 0 0;
}
.buttons{
    width:300px;
    padding:20px 0 0;
}
button{
    width:50px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
#smaller, #muchSmaller{
    float:left;
}
#bigger, #muchBigger{
    float:right;
}
```

**JS**

```
var status=document.getElementById("status");
var top=document.getElementById("top");
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var rotation=0;
for( var i=0,il = buttons.length; i< il; i ++ ){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
    rotation=rotation+parseFloat(this.value);
    top.style.transform="perspective(150px) rotateY(" + rotation + "deg)";
    status.innerHTML="Rotation:<br>" + rotation + "deg";
    };
};
```

Comment: side-question: Why do you use `for(var i=0, il=buttons.length; i<il; i++){` instead of just `for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){`?

Comment: @myfunkyside It's a leftover from previous code, just forgot to clean it up.